# OctoberCms plugin and composer dependencies

Tags: laravel, plugins, composer-php, octobercms

I've created OctoberCms plugin and it have a few dependencies. So I've added them to **composer.json** in plugin dir.

I've saw similar in *qub/clockwork*

But nor of install plugin ,refresh it or composer update didn't install plugin dependencies.

Comment: can you please paste code of plugins.php files code ?

Comment: http://pastie.org/9871778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added dependencies only in composer but you need to register service provider(alias if you want)

Here is a procedure to use laravel packages into OctoberCMS`s plugin

1. **Require the third party plugin in(you have completed this)**

   You firstly need to composer require the third party package into yours.in development you have to fire composer update/install manually, on market place OC automatically fires when plugin installed/updated.
2. **Register the plugins Service Provider**

   In your Plugin.php's `boot()` method, add `\App::register('\Third\Party\ServiceProvider');`. This is how you register a third party ServiceProvider automatically.
3. **Register any Alias's** 
   In your Plugin.php's boot() method under any ServiceProvider lines, if you then need to add an Alias it can be done with

   `$alias = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance()->alias('YourAlias', 'Third\Party\Facade');`

please refer this code https://github.com/anand-patel/oc-wysiwyg-editors/blob/master/Plugin.php#L60

Comment: But I see plugin in admin part, and it working fine. So I need service provider to run composer dependencies?

Comment: In laravel after installing(composer update /install ) any package you need to register service provider right, same way you need to register service providers in October cms plugin in plugin.php file